# I tried everything but could'nt get it right i was'ent able to add data-offset i tried using jquery too

Tags: bootstrap-4

Please help me, I tried using jquery to but it does not work either
i tried this

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="80">
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: this didn't help: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me 1 and half year later I couldn't get the offset for the scroll spy right. The problem was that i didn't added the bootstrap class for the scrool spy. Noob mistake